# Calculator for $Ax=b$ where $A$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have found many online calculators that can calculate $Ax=b$ only when $A$ isn't singular. However in most of my exercises, $A$ is singular and I want to ensure that I have found the right solution. So is there any free tool that can give a relationship for the infinite solutions(and the conditions for $b$) with $b$ being unknown?
Example

A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&4&6\\2&5&7\\3&9&12\end{bmatrix}
b = \begin{bmatrix}b1\\b2\\b3\\b4\end{bmatrix}
Solve Ax=b

Comment: Yes, you can use any CAS, for example Maple, Mathematica or Sage. On the other hand, you can simply take your solution and compute $Ax$ by hand to make the test without a computer. Also, $Ax=b$ need not have infinitely many solutions (what do you mean by "infinite solutions"?).

Comment: @Pooya There could be no solutions or there could be infinite. So i want a calculator that doesnt tell me "Singular Matrix, cant find a solution". Maybe now you understand my question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, i will try it. Arent there infinite solutions when there is a free variable?

Comment: No, take for example a matrix over a finite field, for cryptography.

Comment: @Jordan [symolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/linear-system-of-equations-calculator/x%20%2B%20y%20%3D%201%2C%202x%20%2B%202y%20%3D%202) seems to work for this purpose

Comment: It is really inconvenient for bigger matrices